# Estimating and Improving the accuracy of fourier transform in the low frequency sector

Tags: fft, fourier-transform

I have a time series file which starts with 1 and then quickly tends to oscillating about 0.001. The time series has a resolution of 0.01s and has 10^6 sequential points starting from t=0. The goal is to study the divergence of the fourier transform at Zero frequency. Is there any trick that can be employed to improve the accuracy in the low frequency sector?

Comment: What measurement are you trying to improve the accuracy of?  (Hz, amplitude, time, phase, or ???). What current accuracy are you getting?

Comment: I am tryingg to improve the accuracy of the amplitude. The phase turns out to be exactly Zero always. In particular, based on the parameters that I have given, i.e, dt=0.01 and T=10^6, I expect that there is a $\omega$ below which the FFT returns essentially junk. I want to improve that $\omega$

Comment: Try zero-padding the input signal